# Remove IDs with fewer than 9 unique observations

Tags: r, dplyr, unique

I am trying to filter my data and remove IDs that have fewer than 9 unique month observations. I would also like to create a list of IDs that includes the count.

I've tried using a few different options:

```
library(dplyr)
count <- bind %>% group_by(IDS) %>% filter(n(data.month)>= 9) %>%       ungroup()
count2 <- subset(bind, with(bind, IDS %in% names(which(table(data.month)>=9))))
```

Neither of these worked.

This is what my data looks like:

```
   data.month   ID
           01    2
           02    2
           03    2
           04    2
           05    2
           05    2
           06    2
           06    2
           07    2
           07    2
           07    2
           07    2
           07    2
           08    2
           09    2
           10    2
           11    2
           12    2
           01    5
           01    5
           02    5
           01    7
           01    7
           01    7
           01    4
           02    4
           03    4
           04    4
           05    4
           05    4
           06    4
           06    4
           07    4
           07    4
           07    4
           07    4
           07    4
           08    4
           09    4
           10    4
           11    4
           12    4
```

In the end, I would like a this:

```
IDs
2
3
```

I would also like this

```
IDs  Count
2     12
5     2
7     1
4     12
```

So far this code is the closest, but still just gives error codes:

```
count <- bind %>%
  group_by(IDs) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(bind$data.month >=9)))
```

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
>         Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `n_distinct`

To remove `ID`s with less than 9 unique observations

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(data.month) >= 9) %>%
  pull(ID) %>% unique

#[1] 2 4
```

Or

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(data.month) >= 9) %>%
  distinct(ID)

#     ID
#  <int>
#1     2
#2     4
```

---

For unique counts of each `ID`

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(count = n_distinct(data.month))


#     ID count
#   <int> <int>
#1     2    12
#2     4    12
#3     5     2
#4     7     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `unique` and `length`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Count=length(unique(data.month)))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID Count
  <int> <int>
1     2    12
2     4    12
3     5     2
4     7     1
```

If want to get the ID

```
df%>%group_by(ID)%>%summarise(Count=length(unique(data.month)))%>%filter(Count>9)%>%select(ID)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
     ID
  <int>
1     2
2     4
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
library( data.table )
```

**ID's with 9 obervations or more**

```
unique( DT[, if (.N >= 9) .SD, by = .(data.month)]$ID )
#[1] 2 4
```

**#Unique ID's per month**

```
unique(DT, by = c("data.month", "ID"))[, .(counts = .N), by = .(IDs = ID)]
#    IDs counts
# 1:   2     12
# 2:   5      2
# 3:   7      1
# 4:   4     12
```

**sample data**

```
DT <- fread("data.month   ID
           01    2
            02    2
            03    2
            04    2
            05    2
            05    2
            06    2
            06    2
            07    2
            07    2
            07    2
            07    2
            07    2
            08    2
            09    2
            10    2
            11    2
            12    2
            01    5
            01    5
            02    5
            01    7
            01    7
            01    7
            01    4
            02    4
            03    4
            04    4
            05    4
            05    4
            06    4
            06    4
            07    4
            07    4
            07    4
            07    4
            07    4
            08    4
            09    4
            10    4
            11    4
            12    4")
```